# align slider Horizontal Thumb in centre windows phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, slider, alignment

**i want to align slider Horizontal Thumb in centre (white point) 
how can i do this.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `Minimum` and `Maximum` of the Slider and `Value` halfway between them:

```
<Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="10" Value="5"/>
```